# Call JSP method from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have the above js and JSP code, I want to invoke `procedureCall()` while clicking on `ok` button on confirm window poopup (inside "if" statement). **Is it possible and if yes, how it can be done?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function confirmDelete() {
            var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete");
            if (answer == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
```

JSP piece:

```
<%!    public void procedureCall(int cId) {
            String procedureCall = "{call NEW_PORTING_PRC.delete_album_metadata(cId)}";
                try (CallableStatement cal = conn.prepareCall(procedureCall);) {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

javascript runs in your browser, your java code is deployed in your container(Tomcat).
So only way to invoke this is via a Web call. Your javascript should invoke an ajax call to one servlet(configured in web.xml) and this servlet should invoke your java method.
like from JS you write as

```
 $.get('URLofServlet');
```

OR

**what you can try is submit the JSp with some parameters and reloading the JSP..**

```
if (answer == true) 
{
   document.getElementById("param1").value='paramvalue';
   document.getElementById("myForm").action='yourJspPath.jsp';
   document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Also I assume id and name will both be 'param1' for simplicity..
and in scriptlet you can do like

```
<%
    if(request.getParamter("param1")=='paramvalue'){procedureCall();}
%>
```

Just to add I will recommend to remove scriplets and use ajax as in first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use **form submission or ajax request or framework action** to go back end and process the things needed for you.In your approach its not possible I think. 
And please dont use scriplets in jsp,its not a good practice.